# How to use selenium on SmartTV browser

Tags: python, selenium, samsung-smart-tv, remotewebdriver

I know that `selenium` can be used for `Android` devices by starting `adb-server`, `chromedriver` and then creating `webdriver.Remote()` instance... I'm wondering if there a similar way to operate with web-browser on Samsung SmartTV device using `selenium`. If it's possible, how can I implement it with `Python`?

Answer (score 1):

Not really selenium and python. Samsung has provided automation testing interface in Java: References below:

[Automatic Testing Tool download page](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload)

[Automatic Testing Tool Guide](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d32/index.html)

Source: [Test Automation Tool For SMART TV Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874501/test-automation-tool-for-smart-tv-apps)

Comment: Yeah... I know about this tool and have even tried it, but seems that it allow only to test SmartTV apps on TV emulator and just for 2014 year models

Comment: Links are dead.